# Align images in institute in tikzposter

Tags: tikzposter

I would like to align three figures by their center inside the `institute` command in `tikzposter`.

In beamer, I would use `columns` but it is not possible to do so inside `institute`. Currently I'm just importing the figures using `includegraphics` and spacing them with `hspace`.

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\usepackage{mwe}

\title{Poster Title}

\author{Author} 

\institute{
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics{example-image-c}
}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on this site you are much more likely to get help if you can provide code that others can copy and test. For images you can use the images that come with the `mwe` package, see https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mwe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a command `\midlinegraphic` that takes 2 arguments: the graphic height and filename, which then uses `\raisebox` to shift the graphic down by half that height.

##### MWE

```latex
\documentclass[demo]{tikzposter}
\newcommand{\midlinegraphic}[2]{%
  \raisebox{-#1/2}{\includegraphics[height=#1]{#2}}}
\institute{
  \midlinegraphic{1cm}{A}
  \midlinegraphic{3cm}{A}
  \midlinegraphic{2cm}{A}
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

##### Result

[image: result of mwe]